# A sci-fi prison break movie where multiple people die while trying to break out

Tags: story-identification, movie

I really cannot remember much about the movie but it was like a futuristic prison. People die throughout the escape and at the end it’s just the main character and his sidekick. At the end of the movie I believe a semi truck runs over the side kick and kills him.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?  What made the prison futuristic?

Answer (score 11):

Is this ***[Fortress](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106950/)*** (1992)...?

> In a future, private underground prison/Fortress, the inmates are computer controlled with CCTV, dream readers and devices that can cause pain or death. John and his illegally pregnant wife are inside but want to escape before birth.

There's more than one cut of the ending, but in one version, the protagonist, Brennick, escapes the prison along with one other inmate, Gomez, who ends up being run over and killed by a semi-truck remotely controlled by the same AI that ran the prison.

You can view that scene in the video clip below.

Comment: It's hilarious how in movies characters run down the road or otherwise straight away from a pursuing vehicle / falling starship instead of just swerving out of its path.

Comment: @Organic Marble - TV Tropes refers to this as [1-Dimensional Thinking](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OneDimensionalThinking). Likely a reference to Khan's "two-dimensional thinking" in _Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan_.

Comment: That's great! I note the *Prometheus* illustration which is exactly the other example I was thinking of.

Comment: Is that the highlander?

Comment: @Mad Physicist - Connor MacLeod was another of Christopher Lambert's roles, yes.